# How to check if the entered data is exist in SQLite?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I have a table name `Staff` in my `PosMain` SQLite database that contains attributes `StaffId` , `StaffName`

I have one windows named `LoginWindows` function like a `Login` page with one textbox called `txtStaffId`.

what I want is when user key in their id in `txtStaffId`, the system will check whether their Id exist in the table `Staff` or not. if exist then the system will go to my main windows `PosWindows` and get their data such as `StaffId` and `StaffName`.

the problem is I don't find a way to check whether the Id key in in the `txtStaffId` exist or not.

I used this code but it only get the first data in my table since I'm using `FirstOrDefault`. This code is at my Business Layer called `SalesmanBo`

```
 public int GetStaffId(int staffId)
    {
        try
        {

            using (PosMainDBContext db = new PosMainDBContext())
            {

                return db.Staff.Select(s => s.StaffId).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CustomExceptionHandling customExceptionHandling = new CustomExceptionHandling();
            customExceptionHandling.CustomExHandling(ex.ToString());
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

This is the code at my `LoginWindows` to login

```
 private void txtStaffId_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SalesmanBO salesmanBO = new SalesmanBO();
            Staff staff = new Staff();

            if (e.Key == Key.Return)
            {

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtStaffId.Text))
                {
                    int salesmanId = Int32.Parse(txtStaffId.Text);
                    int staffId = salesmanBO.GetStaffId(staff.StaffId);

                    if (salesmanId == staffId )
                    {
                        PosWindows posWindows = new PosWindows();
                        posWindows.Show();
                        this.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("ID not Valid", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Key In your ID", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                CustomExceptionHandling customExceptionHandling = new CustomExceptionHandling();
                customExceptionHandling.CustomExHandling(ex.ToString());
            }

    }
```

Can you help me with this. I'm new with WPF and SQLITE

Comment: There are many wrong things in this code. Example, You passed `staffId` in `GetStaffId` method but never used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many wrong things in the code you provided. Example, You passed `staffId` in `GetStaffId` method but never used it. I suggest to check for `Staff` entity than only `staffId` because it can be used further. Check following improved version to get some idea.

```
public Staff GetStaffById(int staffId)
{
    try
    {
        using (PosMainDBContext db = new PosMainDBContext())
        {
            return db.Staff.Where(s => s.StaffId == staffId).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CustomExceptionHandling customExceptionHandling = new CustomExceptionHandling();
            customExceptionHandling.CustomExHandling(ex.ToString());
            return null; // changed return 0 to return null
        }
    }
}
```

Change following lines of code in `txtStaffId_KeyDown`event.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtStaffId.Text))
{
    int salesmanId = Int32.Parse(txtStaffId.Text);
    staff = salesmanBO.GetStaffById(salesmanId);


    if (staff!=null) // no need to check salesmanId == staff.StaffId as we already checked while querying it.
    {
        PosWindows posWindows = new PosWindows();
        posWindows.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ID not Valid", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

In `GetStaffById` method,  change return type to `return null`;

No need to create new `Staff` instance. Change `Staff staff = new Staff();` to `Staff staff;`

Comment: okay now when I enter the valid `StaffId` it working fine. that means I can go to my `PosWindows` but when I enter unvalid `StaffId` it does not go to `PosWindows` but it does not prompt the message `ID not Valid`. how can I do that ? Is that some code like `if(salesmanId == staff ) {..}'

Comment: @raynaqarla Please debug your code and see if any error is there or not. I changed code. See update in my answer. Check if you catch block is executing or not.

Comment: @raynaqarla Kindly check new update in my answer. Because you create new instance of `Staff`, it won't be null in case it does not find anything in DB.